# What font and size Salesforce use in labels by default?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, label

[image]

I want to know what font and size salesforce uses in labels as in this picture .

Comment: right click [inspect element](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) to check =P

Comment: If you're trying to make the label and value use the same font/size/weight, I'd recommend _against doing that_. I don't know a lot about graphic design, but I think I know enough to say that the difference here _is deliberate_. The difference helps the eye distinguish between the label and the value (and the spacing helps distinguish between fields).

Comment: @DerekF Im trying to create a form using lwc and i've changed label name with the lightning-input-field but it turned black and bigger size so im trying to use css to make it look like defaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Salesforce Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) (SLDS) is what you seek! The great thing about Lightning Web Components is that you can simply apply SLDS classes to your markup and get Salesforce styles in your components. Great way to make your components match the rest of the Salesforce UX.

I believe the labels in this case are using the Text Title font: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/text/#Title

So give your text the class `slds-text-title`

Comment: thats a great option thanks

Comment: I used this too  label {

    font-family:"Arial";

font-size:9pt;
color:#464646;

}